# Google Analytics not tracking goals in event tracking

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have set up event tracking in Google Analytics as shown below, but when test it with triggering the event, it doesn't show any goals! Can you help?

[image]

Comment: I have also added event tracking code to the button

Comment: Do you see the expected events in the Behaviour > Events > Top events report?